# How do I get the next row of database results from a button click using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm using Node.js to serve my webpage and get the database results from mysql. Right now I have it successfully connected and showing the first row of data.(I'm using these as button values in the html code below) However, I want the user to be able to click a button and get the next row of data.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  // working connection
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM my_table limit 10", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else{
      sandbox.big1Value = result[0].big1;
      sandbox.big2Value = result[0].big2;
    }
  });
});

app.get('/mypage', function (req, res) {
    res.render('mypage', { dbinput: sandbox });
});
```

```
<button type="button" id="big1" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value=<%= dbinput.big1Value %> ><%= dbinput.big1Value %> </button>
<button type="button" id="big2" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value=<%= dbinput.big2Value %>><%= dbinput.big2Value %> </button>
<!-- I want this button to get the next set of values -->
<button type="button" id="next" onclick="doSomething()" value="Next">Next One</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using limit and offset in mysql [From documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#id1026131)

> Syntax: `LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}`

Here in your case you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 10, 10;  # Retrieve rows 11-20
```

Comment: I know how to get more results from mysql. The question is how to I display the next data on my webpage.
I appreciate the help.

Comment: You want to perform pagination right? What you can do is, create your API using express.js, get count of number of rows, divide them with your limit say 10 and display buttons, now you can route these button to page numbers, For example `get/<page number>` [You can checkout tutorial here](https://buildcoding.com/pagination-nodejs-with-mysql-database/)

Comment: There is a library which can make your task easy, try [datatable.js](https://datatables.net/)